# RecyclerView items not changed after Fragment attach and detach

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have `Fragment` A, B in the application.I have set `Recyclerview` on Fragment A using API call.I have one method `deleteEntry()` in Fragment B, due to which one item gets deleted from API data and I come to Fragment A after deleting the item.
  This is the code after API call `deleteEntry` to move to Fragment A

```
CurrentStatus status=new CurrentStatus();
            Busy table=new Busy();
            tx=fm.beginTransaction();
            tx.replace(R.id.frame,new ChooseTab());
            tx.detach(status);
            tx.attach(status);
            tx.detach(table);
            tx.attach(table);
            tx.commit();
```

But After I go to Fragment A the RecyclerView item is still visible even though the API calls again to display modified API data while replacing the Fragment.I need to manually again call the same API to refresh and then Item is gone.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete the entry from the list you have passed to the adapter of the recyclerView and then call notify on the adapter like this -

```
    list.remove(position); // to remove the item from the list
    recyclerAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position); // to notify the adapter
```

where position is the index of the item in the list to be removed.
After this, the item will be removed from the recyclerView and no longer visible.

Comment: But I don't have access to Recyclerview Adapter in Fragment B.

Comment: You can communicate between 2 fragments via the parent activity. Make a function in Fragment A which contains the above logic and call it from Fragment B via the parent activity.

Comment: what about index ?

Comment: If you are storing the data in ArrayList, you can find the index using ArrayList.indexOf(item) method or simply after removing the item from the list, call notifyDataSetChanged on adapter though it's not that efficient.